# Unexpected Rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess

On localhost, in one of my folders, files are accessible like `http://localhost/folder/map` instead of `http://localhost/folder/map.php`. It's probably because of something wrong with Apache's configuration but I'm stuck here and nothing comes to my mind.

Comment: What is your .htaccess content?

Comment: As suggested by @userNOID post the content of your `.htaccess` so we can see if there is any rule that would do that, for example a rule to remove the .php extension of the URL.

Comment: This is usually the “fault” of [Options MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#options) being set.

Comment: my .htaccess file is empty. and when I set `Option -MultiViews` I get a 500 error.

Comment: @HakanAktaş you're missing a `s` as in `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews`

Comment: It's my mistake, I actually used `Options` in htaccess. I still get a HTTP 500. I've set `AllowOverride` to `All` but it still makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file called `index.php` or `index.html` in your `http://localhost/folder/map` folder, Apache will run that file when you just enter the directory name as a browser url.

This is what makes `http://localhost` run a page rather than just showing you a directory listing, or show a blank page.

This is probably the reason that you see a valid page when just keying in the `http://localhost/folder/map` url.

Comment: there's also no folder called map.